# Bounding box for a number of lat lon

Tags: google-maps

I have a number of lat long  list for e.g. 100.909423828125 4.784468966579362,101.337890625 4.543570279371759,101.019287109375 4.521666342614804,100.931396484375 4.532618393971778,100.909423828125 4.784468966579362,100.909423828125. What I need is that to build a bounding box for all this point based on certain radius in meters. What is the best mechanism to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Is this [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com), or the [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics) (or something else)?

Comment: @geocodezip I am working on google maps api v3 now.I have this sample here on this link http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL210/JSTS_Example/jsts_example.asp. Here if you draw a linestring and set the distance and press the execute button you will get the buffer area.

Comment: @geocodezip it is based on this https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts#readme and can we use it via google map api v3 too?